# Spring-data mongodb geo query

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, spring-data

I am using spring-data to communicate with mongodb,I am looking for a way to perform geo query which will retrieve near by profiles by given geo point from DB, my requirements from the query  are:

1) limit by distance 
2) limit by number of returned profiles 
3) additional search according time field in the profiles document
4) the ability to include / exclude fields from the retrieved documents

At first I used **mongoTemplate.geoNear** method...

```
   Query criteria = new Query(Criteria.where("time").gte("some_date")); 
   criteria.fields().exclude("friends");
    NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(point).maxDistance(maxDistance)
            .num(limit).query(criteria);
    GeoResults<Profile> result = mongoTemplate
            .geoNear(query, Profile.class);<br/>
```

But then I realized that mongo does not support in including/excluding fields in geoNear queries.
So I am thinking about **Near** query, it seems that the only way to perform that kind of "complex" query in spring-data is by using **@Query** annotation,is there a way to support requirements 2,3 above in that kind of query? any other way ?
Thanks

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Assaf - Did you got the solution? Please help me.. Thanks, Neha

Comment: any news here? how can I exclude fields?

Answer (score 1):

You question actually features the pieces to all of the answer you need. You only need to use query.addCriteria to put them all together.

1: Use a Circle with a radius
2. Use Query.limit(count)
3. Use the Query.where("date").gte()
4. Use fields to project results

**Here you go**

```
    Point point = new Point(6.12343, 3.121211);
    Distance distance = new Distance(100, Metrics.KILOMETERS);
    Circle circle = new Circle(point, distance);
    Integer resultLimit = 20; //Limit to 20 records
    Criteria geoCriteria = Criteria.where("position").withinSphere(circle);
    Criteria timeCriteria = Criteria.where("time").gte(new Date());
    Query query = Query.query(geoCriteria);
    query.addCriteria(timeCriteria);
    query.fields().exclude("friends");
    mongoTemplate.find(query, Profile.class);
```